# jquery class replace html

Tags: jquery, html

HTML Code

```
<td class='money'>192.13</td><td class='money'>85.23</td>
```

Task

I would like to replace in the content of all cells with class money the "." with ","

Solution1

```
var value = $(".money").html(); 
value = value.replace(".", ","); 
$(".money").html(value);
```

Problem: The value of the first value is replacing all other values.

Solution2

```
$(".money").html().replace(".",",");
```

Problem: does not work

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a setter version of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$(".money").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(".",",")
});
```

your code returns a replaced string for the first td, but it is not set back to the cell.

Answer (score 3):

So, `$('.money')` is a collection of *all* of the DOM elements that match your selector, which is why solution #1 doesn't work. Therefore, you need to look through each of the matched elements and perform your operation individually:

```
$.each($('.money'), function() {
  // $(this) refers to the current matched element in the loop
  var $this = $(this),
    value = $this.html().replace(".", ",");

  $this.html(value);
};
```

After posting, I saw Arun's answer, and it is sexier, so go with that. But I think you could stand to learn from the concepts explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To try and help you understand why it doesn't work, let's read your code:

- Find all `.money` elements, and get the `html` of the first one.
- Replace the `.` with a `,`
- Find all `.money` elements, and set their `html` to that first value.

Second code:

- Find all `.money` elements, and get the `html` of the first one.
- Replace the `.` with a `,`
- Do bugger all.

This is one of the many problems I have with jQuery: ambiguous functions. `.html()` returns the HTML of the *first* element in the set, but `.html(value)` replaces the HTML of *all* elements in the set.

Anyway, the jQuery you're looking for is:

```
$(".money").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(".",","));
});
```

Consider also [this Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".money"),function(e) {
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(".",",");
});
```

While is may look like more or messier code, it is *many many* times faster than any jQuery solution.

And finally, a hybrid solution that combines performance with browser compatibility:

```
$(".money").each(function() {
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = this.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(".",",");
});
```

Enjoy!